# Incorrect result in SQL. Subquery is borked, but why?

Tags: postgresql, peewee

I have this Peewee query:

```
stats = (
    Assignment.select(
        Type.name,
        fn.COUNT(Type.id).alias('total'),
        Assignment.select(
            fn.COUNT(Assignment.id)
        ).where(
            (Assignment.due_date < fn.Now()) & (StudentCourses.student == self) & (Assignment.type == Type.id)
        ).group_by(Assignment.type, StudentCourses.student).alias('completed')
    )
    .naive().join(Type)
    .join(StudentCourses, on=(StudentCourses.course == Assignment.course))
    .where(StudentCourses.student == self)
    .order_by(Type.id)
    .group_by(Type.id, Type.name, StudentCourses.student)
)
```

which results in the following SQL

```
SELECT t.NAME
    ,COUNT(t.id) AS total
    ,(
        SELECT COUNT(ass.id)
        FROM assignment AS ass
        WHERE (
                (
                    (ass.due_date < Now())
                    AND (sc.student_id = 61)
                    )
                AND (ass.type_id = t.id)
                )
        GROUP BY ass.type_id,sc.student_id
        ) AS completed
FROM assignment AS a
INNER JOIN type AS t ON (a.type_id = t.id)
INNER JOIN studentcourses AS sc ON (sc.course_id = a.course_id)
WHERE (sc.student_id = 61)
GROUP BY t.id
    ,t.NAME
    ,sc.student_id
ORDER BY t.id
```

which returns this dataset:

```
   name   | total | completed
----------+-------+-----------
 Homework |    18 |        88
 Test     |     7 |        20
 Final    |     2 |
 Custom   |    29 |        85
 In Class |    18 |        49
(5 rows)
```

Problem is that the completed section is wrong. It should be this:

```
   name   | total | completed
----------+-------+-----------
 Homework |    18 |        16
 Test     |     7 |        5
 Final    |     2 |        0
 Custom   |    29 |        24
 In Class |    18 |        9
```

Could someone help em figure out what's going wrong here? I don't think it's a Peewee problem because when I run the above SQL in the Postgres console, it also returns the same incorrect dataset.

**UPDATE**
@coleifer, I tried your suggestion, which resulted in the following SQL:

```
SELECT "t1"."name",
  (SELECT COUNT("t2"."id")
   FROM "assignment" AS t2
   INNER JOIN "studentcourses" AS t3 ON ("t3"."course_id" = "t2"."course_id")
   WHERE (("t3"."student_id" = 61)
          AND ("t2"."type_id" = "t1"."id"))
   GROUP BY "t2"."type_id") AS total,
  (SELECT COUNT("t2"."id")
   FROM "assignment" AS t2
   INNER JOIN "studentcourses" AS t3 ON ("t3"."course_id" = "t2"."course_id")
   WHERE (("t3"."student_id" = 61)
          AND ("t2"."type_id" = "t1"."id"))
   GROUP BY "t2"."type_id" HAVING ("t2"."due_date" < NOW())) AS completed
FROM "type" AS t1
```

Which unfortunately returned this error:

```
ERROR:  column "t2.due_date" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 13:    GROUP BY "t2"."type_id" HAVING ("t2"."due_date" < NOW()))...
```

I tried putting `t2.due_date` into the group by and got another error:

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Thoughts?

Comment: I tried a different approach using HAVING clauses, let me know if it's close.

Comment: Any feedback? Are we on the right track?

Comment: lol bro cole? cole???

Comment: Hah. Just goes to show you that I'm an idiot Charles. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the SQL query that produces the results you want, I'd be happy to help you translate it into "peewee". Can you write a query that gives you the results you're after?

---

Just trying to unravel what you've got here....

I think you have an issue with your outer join on StudentCourse not having the intended effect on your subquery counting assignments. I'm gonna try a different approach, maybe it will work?

```
# I have no idea if this will actually work.
total = (Assignment
         .select(fn.COUNT(Assignment.id))
         .join(
             StudentCourses, on=(
                 StudentCourses.course == Assignment.course))
         .where(
             (StudentCourses.student == self) &
             (Assignment.type == Type.id))
         .group_by(Assignment.type))

# Maybe HAVING will work?
completed = total.having(Assignment.due_date < fn.NOW())

# This query just selects types
stats = Type.select(
    Type.name,
    total.alias('total'),
    completed.alias('completed'))
```

Comment: Coleifer, writing the query is the hard part. If I had that, I think I might be able to come up with a Peewee query. :(

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure I understand your query.

- There seem to be some unnecessary brackets in the where clause in the subquery
- I don't understand the group by student_id since you already have a where student_id = 61 in place
- It doesn't make sense to do a count(t.id) and a group by t.id at the same time.
- I don't understand the ORDER BY t.id in the main query

If I understand what you are trying to do, I would do it like this:

```
select t.name, count(t.id), count(case when a.due_date < Now() then 1 else null end) 
from type t, studentcourses s, assignment a 
where a.course_id = sc.course_id and a.type_id = t.id and sc.student_id = 61 
group by t.name
```

Comment: "It doesn't make sense to do a count(t.id) and a group by t.id at the same time." --- it does. It is identical to `COUNT(*)` in this case (which should have been used instead actually)